# How can a function in C++ return either a value or a reference with minimal copying?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that delegates to two others, returning either a reference or value depending on some runtime condition:

```
X by_value() { ... }
const X& by_reference() { ... }

?? foo(bool b) {
  if (b) {
    return by_value();
  } else {
    return by_reference();
  }
}
```

I'd like to choose the return type of my function so that callers induce minimal copying; e.g.:

```
const X& x1 = foo(true);   // No copies
const X& x2 = foo(false);  // No copies
X x3 = foo(true);          // No copies, one move (or zero via RVO)
X x4 = foo(false);         // One copy
```

In all cases except the last, there shouldn't be a need (based on the *runtime* behavior) to copy the return value.

If the return type of `foo` is `X`, then there will be an extra copy in case 2; but if the return type is `const X&`, then cases 1 and 3 are undefined behavior.

Is it possible, via returning some sort of proxy, to ensure that the above uses have minimal copies?

---

**Explanation**: Since there's been significant pushback of the form "you're doing it wrong", I thought I'd explain the reason for this.

Imagine I have an array of type `T or function<T()>` (meaning the elements of this array are either of type `T`, or they're functions returning `T`). By the "value" of an element of this array, I mean, either the value itself or the return value when the function is evaluated.

If this `get_value_of_array(int index)` returns by value, then in the cases where the array contains just an element, I'm forced to do an extra copy. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

---

**Further note**: If the answer is, "That's impossible", that's fine with me. I'd love to see a proof of this, though - ideally of the form "Suppose there were a type `Proxy<X>` that solved your problem. Then...`

Comment: Doesn't your compiler provide copy elision?

Comment: I'm very skeptical that a compiler would elide the copy in case #2 - if you sketch this out with logging in the copy constructor, both gcc and clang show the copy constructor called.

Comment: I feel like mangling *return-by-value* and *return-by-reference* semantics simply to try and avoid copies is a bad idea. Trust RVO/elision to do its job, and return a reference when you really mean to return a reference and return a value when you really mean to return a value.

Comment: @aruisdante, the thing is, I have code that looks exactly like I've sketched, with the return type of my function `X`. This causes extra copies - RVO and elision don't appear to do anything here (see my above comment). If you believe elision will happen here, how do you prove it?

Comment: @JesseBeder Of course it calls the copy constructor in case #2. You returned a reference when you declare that you're returning a value. If it elison'd that and actually returned the reference object, it would break the return-by-value semantics. It needs to perform a copy in that case because the object it is returning is no longer locally-scoped, and so RVO can't be applied. Read the wiki entry on [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), it talks about these cases.

Comment: @aruisdante, exactly - but based on the actual runtime behavior here (with a magical return value for `foo` that does the right thing), you don't need a copy in case #2.

Comment: Sure you do. If ``X foo(bool b = false)`` You're declaring you're returning a value, but the actual value you're returning is a reference. The compiler is simply trying to resolve the scope conflict, which states that the return from ``foo`` should be decoupled from the scope of ``foo``, which returning a reference without a copy would violate.

Comment: @aruisdante, I deliberately left out a return type to `foo`. Certainly if the return type is a value, then it must copy; but I want some sort of proxy return type because the *hand-described* behavior of this function doesn't need to copy.

Comment: I don't understand a situation where the internal return type from your function would need to be a reference, and yet you don't want reference semantics. I think you better need to describe what actually happens if you want a good answer. You could obviously create some adaptor class that simply holds a reference to an ``X`` and return that, so elision of the returned value would always happen. But then you're not actually returning by value that ``X`` ever. This is the point I'm trying to make, you seem to want to violate the constraints of return-by-value/return-by-reference.

Comment: @aruisdante, I've added an explanation of what's going on here - hopefully that helps!

Comment: Jesse, distancing myself from the rest of the static and focusing on your posted question, your point on what happens in case #2 when the return type is by-val (i.e. a copy is made and you're trying to avoid that) seems the spot that is griefing you. If that is *not* correct I'll be moving on; otherwise I'll stick around.

Comment: Implicit = bad, explicit = good. Make all your problems disappear by being more explicit. Simple. {hint: you really have two functions, which you have conflated into one with selection at run time}

Comment: @WhozCraig, that's correct

Comment: Return a `variant<T,T const&>`.

Comment: @Mankarse, how is the variant implemented? If it stores a `T` by value no matter what (even if it's empty), then it'll copy the (default-constructed) `T` when only the reference is needed, which sorta defeats the point

Comment: @JesseBeder: Usually variants are implemented by containing a `char` array of the maximum alignment and size of the required types, and constructing the relevant value into that array. There would be no default construction.

Comment: @Mankarse, nifty, I didn't know that! I passed right over this idea because I assumed it would have to construct both :)

Comment: @JesseBeder: It seems you are already using a sum-type for the values in your array ("Imagine I have an array of type `T or function<T()>`"). What are you using for this, if not a variant class?

Comment: @Mankarse, I'm actually using parallel arrays. Cache locality is pretty important here, and in any case, the (very very) common case is the value array - the function array is necessary, but extremely rarely used. So the most frequently thing that happens is to look up something in the value array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [sum-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (that is, a type whose possible values are "the possible `X` values *plus* the possible `X const&` values").

In C++, these are usually called `variant`. These are usually implemented as a tag plus an appropriately sized and aligned array, and only hold exactly one value at runtime. Alternatively, they are implemented with dynamic allocation and the classic [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

For example, with [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html), you could declare your function to return `boost::variant<X, X const&>` ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0c30c1eb9c8c78d)):

```
boost::variant<X, X const&> foo(bool b) {
  if (b) {
    return by_value();
  } else {
    return by_reference();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you add a note about the implementation (avoiding default construction, etc.)? If I run across this again, I'd hate to have to dig through the comments to find it :)

Comment: I replaced the `#define` in my answer with your function (modified to call `foo_false` and `foo_true`), but with g++ I get the error `error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const my::X&' from expression of type 'boost::variant<my::X, const my::X&>'` for the first of the OP's declarations. What am I doing wrong? Can you give an example that includes the OP's declarations?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Clearly, OP's declarations were meant to convey the idea, and not the exact syntax. It is impossible to get that exact syntax in the OP's situation, as whether the returned value is a reference or a value is determined at run-time, depending on the contents of the array(s) in question.

Comment: still, can you give a concrete example, with the OP's declarations.

Comment: If, for some bizarre reason you continue to think that the problem is a compile-time one (despite the OP repeatedly saying otherwise), it can be done [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8442c89295b0e4a). Even so, I see no reason why you would do that, when you could just store the result in a `variant` and query it as required.

Comment: Readers still upvoting this answer, be advised that **it does not work**.

Comment: Are you just trolling at this point? This answer has clearly helped the OP (as evidenced by the "thanks!" and the fact that it is the accepted answer), so it would appear that I was able to get to the core of the matter rather than getting caught up in superficial syntactic matters. The the exact syntax is not important to the OP, but was only given to exemplify the desired behaviour. My code can provide that desired behaviour, just not the exact syntax. Furthermore, I've demonstrated a modified version that does work with that exact syntax in the OP.

Comment: Types are a compile-time matter, so the proposed syntax is not possible for if the type is determined at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is impossible because whether the caller decides to move or copy the return value (whether it's from a proxy or from your class itself) is a compile-time decision, whereas what you want is to make it a run-time decision. Overload resolution cannot happen at run-time.

The only way out that I can see is to have the *callee* decide this, i.e. by providing a `T &` parameter which it can either move-assign to or copy-assign to depending on what it deems appropriate.
Alternatively, you can pass an `aligned_storage<sizeof(T)>` buffer and have the callee construct the value inside it, if you don't think the caller can be expected to make a "null" instance of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if *really* want to achieve this, here's one rather ugly way:

```
X *foo(bool b, X *value) {
  if (b) {
    *value = get_value();
  } else {
    value = get_pointer_to_value();
  }
  return value;
}
```

Example usage:

```
void examplefunc() {
    X local_store;
    X *result;

    result = foo(true, &local_store);
    assert(result == &local_store);
    use_x_value(*x);

    result = foo(false, &local_store);
    assert(result != &local_store);
    use_x_value(*x);
}
```

Above approach is cumbersome: it needs two local variables and forces using the return value through a pointer. It also exposes a raw pointer, which can't be nicely converted to a smart pointer (putting `local_store` to heap to allow using a smart pointer would make this approach even more complex, not to mention add the overhead of heap allocation). Also, `local_store` is always default-constructed, but if you don't need to make `examplefunc` re-entrant, it can be made `static` (or use thread-local storage for multi-threaded version).

So I have hard time imagining where you would actually want to use this. It'd be simpler to always just return a copied value (and let compiler take care of copy elision when it can), or always return a reference, or maybe always return a `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is bad: Having multiple return types where one is a copy and the other is reference makes the function unpredictable.

Assuming foo is a member function of some classes A, B:

makes

```
X A::foo() { return X(); }
X foo a = A().foo()
```

well defined

and

```
const X& B::foo() { return some_internal_x; }
const X& b = B().foo()
```

a dangling reference

Comment: I understand that returning by reference can lead to a dangling reference; if I promise not to leave a dangling reference, will you answer the question?

Comment: Just because you promise to not do it doesn't mean the compiler can figure out that that would never happen. Hence why it does a copy if you return by value or you get a reference if you return by reference.

Comment: @aruisdante, the compiler doesn't need to prove you're not going to leave a dangling reference to allow you to return by reference (see Dieter's answer).

Comment: Sure, but you've explicitly declared that that is a possibility by returning a reference. Remember that elision/RVO is an optimization that technically violates the C++ specification. It is only allowed in situations where it can **guarantee** that the behavior would be the same if it copied or elisioned, I.E. returning a locally-scoped value.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish what you want (still a bit fuzzy) by passing the variable type to `get_value_of_array`. This would allow it to return two different types and make adjustments based on whether the member of the array is a function or array.

```
struct X
{
    X() { std::cout << "Construct" << std::endl; }
    X(X const&) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
    X(X&&) { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }
};

const X array;
X function() { return X(); }

template<typename ReturnType>
ReturnType get_value_of_array(bool);

template<>
const X& get_value_of_array<const X&>(bool /*isarray*/)
{
    // if (isarray == false) return the cached result of function()
    return array; // gotta build the example yo!
}

template<>
X get_value_of_array<X>(bool isarray)
{
    return isarray ? array : std::move(function());
}

int main()
{
    // Optimizations may vary.
    const X& x1 = get_value_of_array<decltype(x1)>(true);   // No copies or moves
    const X& x2 = get_value_of_array<decltype(x2)>(false);  // No copies or moves.
    X x3 = get_value_of_array<decltype(x3)>(true);          // One copy, one move.
    X x4 = get_value_of_array<decltype(x4)>(false);         // Two moves.
}
```

Thanks to [Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) for the implementation of X.

Answer (score -2):

At the time I'm writing this answer it's not a requirement that the argument to the function `foo` should be computed at run time, or should be allowed to be other than literally `false` or `true`, thus:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace my {
    using std::cout; using std::endl;

    class X
    {
    private:
        X& operator=( X const& ) = delete;

    public:
        X() {}

        X( X const& )
        { cout << "Copy" << endl; }

        X( X&& )
        { cout << "Move" << endl; }
    };
}  // my

auto foo_true()
    -> my::X
{ return my::X(); }

auto foo_false()
    -> my::X const&
{ static my::X const static_x; return static_x; }

#define foo( arg ) foo_##arg()

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace my;

    cout << "A" << endl; const X& x1 = foo(true);   // No copies
    cout << "B" << endl; const X& x2 = foo(false);  // No copies
    cout << "C" << endl; X x3 = foo(true);          // No copies, one move (or zero via RVO)
    cout << "D" << endl; X x4 = foo(false);         // One copy
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have not made myself clear, but the argument to `foo` *is* a runtime argument. (That's why I made it one!)

Comment: @JesseBeder: the only problem here is the *choice* to conflate the two functions.

Comment: it's not a choice, exactly - the (external) caller isn't exactly passing literals `true` or `false` here (this was just a simplified example).